# How to select date , Month , and year from a calendar using selenium with Python

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, pytest

How to select date, Month and year from a calendar using selenium with Python without Hardcoding

Comment: can you share url or html elements of calender?

Comment: U can get "https://www.facebook.com/" from create a new account calendar

Comment: Follow my java code which i mentioned below

Answer (score 0):

```
    import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select;

public class fbcalender {

    static WebDriver driver;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Users\\User\\Downloads\\chromedriver83\\chromedriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
     //Here you can give dates as parameters
        setday(driver,"12","Aug","1999");


    }

    public static void setday(WebDriver driver,String day,String month,String year)
    {
        // Select date
        Select dates=new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("day")));
        dates.selectByValue(day);

        //select month from drop down
        Select Months=new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("month")));
        Months.selectByVisibleText(month);

        //select year
        Select Years=new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("year")));
        Years.selectByVisibleText(year);


    }



}
```